# Помогите сделать удаление строки и редактирование в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я делаю веб приложение To Do List, уже сделал генерацию новых задач при их вводе, но я не очень знаю JS, по этому, погите, пожалуйста :3
Мне надо сделать вместе с задачами генерировались 2 кнопки справа от задачи, одна из которых будет удалять задачу, а вторая - редактировать.

Вот HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ToDo List</title>

  <script src="eel.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Список дел</h1>
        <div id="add">
            <form>
            <input type="text" value="" name="" id="txt1">
            <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="butt();">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS код:

```
body {
    background: #c2e59c; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #c2e59c, #64b3f4); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    }

#txt2 {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Вот JS:

```
 function butt() {
  let cont = document.querySelector(".container");
  let item = document.createElement("div");
  item.className = 'txt2';
  item.textContent = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
  cont.appendChild(item);
}
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт дополнен

```
  var editObj = null;

  function butt() {
      if(editObj !== null) {
          editObj.closest('.txt2').innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt1").value + " <input type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"Edit(this)\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"Delete(this)\">";
          editObj = null;
      } else {
          let cont = document.querySelector(".container");
          let item = document.createElement("div");
          item.className = 'txt2';
          item.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
          item.innerHTML += " <input type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"Edit(this)\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" onclick=\"Delete(this)\">";
          cont.appendChild(item);
          document.getElementById("txt1").value = '';
          editObj = null;
      }
  }

  function Delete(e) {
      e.closest('.txt2').remove();
  }

  function Edit(e) {
      var text2Edit = e.closest('.txt2').innerText;
      document.getElementById('txt1').value = text2Edit;
      editObj = e;
  }
```